# Android facebook upload photo on a feed page

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Hi guys I am trying to upload a photo to a page on Facebook. This is the page i am trying to post the photo https://www.facebook.com/manegedagen/.

I have been using the following code :
 public static void postImageOnWall(Bitmap pBitmap) {

```
    Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    bundle.putString("picture","http://www.demos.com/LangGuage/medal_1.png");
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/2091172661108128/feed",
            null,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                /* handle the result */
                    Log.e("", "");
                }

            }
    ).executeAsync();


}
```

But i am getting an error message: OAuthException: errorMessage: Invalid parameters. I would really appreciate if i can get any guide or help.

Comment: You can not upload photos via the feed endpoint. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos#Creating

Answer (score 0):

Try with parameters not as `null`

see the selected answer from this reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29770773/6011938